# Bootstrap collapse icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make Bootstrap change the navbar list from text to icons from the browser re-sizing instead of making it into a collapse drop down?

For example, make example 1 turn into example 2 just from the browser re-sizing.

Example 1:

> ```
>   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
>     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
>       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
>       <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
>     </ul>
> ```

Example 2:

> ```
>   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
>     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
>       <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
>       <li><a href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></a></li>
>       <li><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></a></li>
>     </ul>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, add some css like this:

```
.nav .glyphicon {
        display: none;
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
    .nav .text {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav .glyphicon {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Then update your `li`s to have a span for both text and the icon:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><span class="text">Home</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
</li>
```

The `@media` styles specify that when the screen width is 300px or less, then hide the text and show the icon. The icon is hidden by default.

EDIT:
I've updated your fiddle to have the switch working. Here's what I did:
http://jsfiddle.net/cPa6b/

- Removed the button in your navbar header
- Removed the collapse styles on your navbar div
- Added 2 new styles in the media query to counteract bootstrap's style (also changed the max-width to 768 to match bootstrap's default):

`.navbar-header, .navbar-nav, .navbar-nav > li { float: left; }`

`.navbar-nav { margin: 5px; }`

You may also consider customizing the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable in bootstrap as mentioned here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Bootstrap is still trying to collapse all of the buttons into that single mobile button. How would I stop that so that the CSS that you mentioned takes over?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle that I can take a look at illustrating the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6524/ 

When re-sizing it, it still turns into the toggle drop down button as opposed to turning into the icons.

Comment: There it goes! Thank you!